# Python: Canopy>> where's a workspace window?

Tags: python, canopy

I'm using the interface called Canopy for coding Python.
I'm new to this, and spent hours to find out the workspace window (just like Matlab's workspace where a programmer can navigate to find variables created)

Any help will be preciously appreciated.
Huge thanks in advance![image]

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there isn't such a pane in Canopy currently.  Send them a feedback request (Help->Feedback/Bugs) and they may include it in the future.  There are couple options:

1) You can use a program like [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which has a workspace window.

2) You can produce your own "workspace" function:

```
# First note the variables present before we make any.  Only variables made after this line are part of the "workspace"
locvars = locals().copy()

# Print out an list of variables that aren't python internal.  We will call the workspace the collection
# of variables which were made after the first instruction executed.
# This function expects the calling namespace to have a variable locvars which is a copy of locals taken before
# any variables were made for inclusion into the "workspace".
def showlocals():
    # Get the calling frame's locals
    import inspect
    locs = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
    locvars = locs['locvars']

    # Get the list of variables in the workspace.
    workspace = [k for (k, v) in locs.items() if k not in locvars.keys() and k[0] != '_' and k != 'locvars' and k != 'showlocals']

    # Print out the names and values of those.
    for (k,v) in locs.items():
        if k in workspace:
            print '%s = %s' % (k, v)

# Now you do your code which produces variables.
x = 5
y = 7

# Everytime you want to print out the variables you call this function.
showlocals()
```

and get an output like this:

```
x = 5
y = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Canopy 1.5, due in October, will include a GUI debugger which provides display / browsing of namespace / variables (as well as debugging functions like breakpoints, stepping through code, etc).